# Display blog post from a specific tag in a page on WordPress 6.4?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I get all the blog posts tagged as say hiking and display them on a my recent hikes page in grid display?

```
<?php $args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tag' => 'hiking'
);

$recent_posts = get_posts($args);?>
```

Or is thery any way to do with with query loop block of WordPress 6.4?

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress, you can achieve this by using the WP_Query class to create a custom query or by utilizing the Query Loop block if you are using WordPress 5.8 or later. Here's an example using both methods:

**Method 1: Using WP_Query:**

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tag' => 'hiking',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // Set to -1 to retrieve all posts
);

$recent_posts = new WP_Query($args);

if ($recent_posts->have_posts()) :
    while ($recent_posts->have_posts()) : $recent_posts->the_post();
        // Display your post content here
        ?>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <div class="post-content">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata(); // Reset the post data
else :
    echo 'No posts found';
endif;
?>
```

**Method 2: Using Query Loop Block (WordPress 5.8 or later):**
Create a new page or edit an existing one.
Add a Query Loop block:
Inside the block editor, add a new block, search for "Query Loop", and add the "Query Loop" block to your page.
In the block settings, you can specify the query parameters, including the tag 'hiking'.
Configure the block to display the desired content.
This block will dynamically fetch and display posts based on the specified query parameters, including the 'hiking' tag.

Choose the method that best fits your needs and the version of WordPress you are using. Method 1 gives you more control and flexibility, while Method 2 is more user-friendly and may be preferred if you want to manage content through the block editor.